# Passing loop data as variable from JavaScript to AJAX via Bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

My code below was used to retrieve records from a loop using  JavaScript. Everything works fine. Each of the records button has a unique id that when click 
should alert `users_id` in a Bootstrap Modal popup.

The problem is that the looped button that contains `users_id` is not alerting anything  when each button is clicked.

Below is the code for retrieving records in JavaScript along with Bootstrap modal button:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.post('users.php', function(response){
            $.each(JSON.parse(response).items, function(i,v) {
                $('.userslist').append('<span>'+v.id+'</span> <a href="#myModal" id="'+v.id+'" class="modalLink"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Profile</a>');
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Below is the code  for posting the `users_id` and then alert it:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".modalLink").click(function() {
            var id = $(this).attr("id");
            alert(id);
            var dataString = 'id='+ id;
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "ajax_modal.php",
                data: dataString,
                cache: false,
                success: function(data) {      
                    $("#rmm").html(data);
                } 
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

but if I take the Modal button outside the retrieve records in a javascript loop
it will alert users_id and everything will work fine as in code below

```
<a href="#myModal" id="'+v.id+'" class="modalLink"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Profile</a>
```

Can someone help me make each of the JavaScript  looped button to post its own unique `users_id` and then alert it in a Bootstrap modal popup. I have attached a screen shot of the result obtained from the JavaScript loop.

[image: Example Result]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question properly;

Try changing

```
$(".modalLink").click(function() {
```

to

```
$(document).on('click', '.modalLink', function() {
```

Without seeing the rest of your code or a working fiddle, I suspect your content is dynamic and JQ cannot bind the click handler, simply because there is no content to bind to. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11878976/5063323) does a good job of explaining the difference between `.on` and `.click`.

If you get the expected result, I would drop the `document` selector and use the closest parent static element.